# Lua - I need a 4 condition if statement

Tags: if-statement, lua

All I’m looking for is for a way to create a Lua if statement that needs to meet 4 conditions before activating, for example

```
If (x == condition1 and x == condition2 and x ~= condition3 and x ~= condition4) then
Return true
End
```

I’m beginning at Lua right now and just want to know if this will work or if there is another way! (If someone has already had his problem/question and has an answer please link me) Thanks

Comment: Yes, connecting the conditions with `and` will work.

Comment: If you want to know if something works, just try it out yourself. Since you're new to Lua, I suggest having a look at the *Programming in Lua* book (available online for free), where very basic questions like that are answered.

Comment: Lua is case-sensitive. `If` is not the same thing as `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this as you have, except that `if`, `return`, and `end` must not be capitalized in Lua, and the parenthesis are not needed in the `if` statement (though this is not a syntax error):

```
if x == condition1 and x == condition2 and x ~= condition3 and x ~= condition4 then
   return true
end
```

But, if you want to return a boolean value, it would be cleaner to return the result of the logical operators directly, avoiding the `if` statement altogether:

```
return x == condition1 and x == condition2 and x ~= condition3 and x ~= condition4
```